# How may I remove duplicate rows by combining the coulmns (comma separated) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to remove duplicates for this table as in Output table in SQL Server.
    Source_Table

```
Name School class Description Start_Date End_Date
Andy MTC    7     Pass        2008       2009
Andy MTC    8     Pass        2009       2010
Andy STC    9     Pass        2010       2011
Andy STC    10    Failed      2011       2012


Output_Table

Name School  class      Description                  Start_Date     End_Date
Andy MTC,STC    7,8,9,10    Pass,Pass,Pass,Failed        2008       2012
```

Comment: *"I need to normalize this table as in Output table in SQL Server"* That isn't normalised, that's ***very*** denormalised.

Comment: @larnu - Thanks, I updated this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using SQL-Server, so I made this answer based of documentation in the Internet, but I think you should use:

```
SELECT Name, STRING_AGG(school,',') AS School, STRING_AGG(class,',') AS Class, STRING_AGG(description,',') AS Description, MIN(start_date) AS Start_date, MAX(end_date) AS End_date FROM source_table GROUP BY Name
```

Read more about `STRING_AGG` at https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/concatenate-rows-using-string_agg

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want aggregation:

```
select name,
       string_agg(distinct school, ','),
       string_agg(class, ',') within group (order by class),
       string_agg(description, ',') within group (order by class),
       min(Start_Date), max(End_Date)
from t
group by name
```